# VBS uninstall application

Tags: vbscript, wmi, wmic

I am trying to get a VBS script together to use as a startup script to uninstall Silverlight if it is a version under 5, but my code keeps giving me a type mismatch when trying to compare the value.

The version is 5.1.10411.0. How do I compare this value to a integer value?

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Caption = 'Microsoft Silverlight'") 
Dim item
For each item in colItems
    prodVer = item.Version
Next
If prodVer < 5 Then
    set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        set oExec = WshShell.Exec("wmic product where caption='Microsoft Silverlight' call uninstall")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

The version value is a string, so to compare it to an integer you first need to extract something that can be converted to an integer.

E.g. to extract the digit preceding the first period;

```
prodVer = "5.1.10411.0"

if (prodVer <> "") then
    prodVer = clng(left(prodVer, instr(prodVer , ".") - 1))

    msgbox prodVer < 5
end if
```